# How to negate duration in XPath

Tags: datetime, xpath, xquery, duration

If `$d` and `$e` are durations, the expression `$d lt -$e` does not work since in [XPath3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) only `op:numeric-unary-minus` is defined and no unary-minus for other types. In other words, unary minus (negation) is not applicable to a duration but to a number only.

How to solve this issue and get the negation of a duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by a number is defined for duration in XPath3, so we can just multiply by `-1` to change the sign of a duration:

`$d lt ( -1 * $e )`

NB: unary minus can be used in [lexical representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration-lexical-repr) of a duration, i.g.

`xs:dayTimeDuration("-PT50S")`